# getGoogleAppId failed with exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Initialize must be called before getGoogleAppId

Tags: java, android

When try to ads put interstitial ads of **AdMob** in Android Studio. always AdMob load failed and log show bellow:

```
E/FA: getGoogleAppId failed with exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
       Initialize must be called before getGoogleAppId.: 
       com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzgp.
                                         getGmpAppId(Unknown Source:720)
```

Anybody can help me please?

Comment: If you updated your ads SDK you need to apply app Id to manifest file

Answer (score 0):

If you updated your ads SDK you need to apply App Id to manifest file. Please check the below code.

```
</activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APP_ID_HERE"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"/>
</application>
```